# Problems with calculated properties and inheritiance using @Formula in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, annotations

Hi I'm pretty new to Hibernate so I might be doing some silly stuff.

I have an entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="criterion")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class AbstractCriteria implements Criteria{

Criteria child;
List<Criteria> parents;

@Override
@OneToOne(targetEntity=AbstractCriteria.class, cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
@Lazy(true)
public Criteria getChild() {
    return _child;
}
```

And I want the parents to be a calculated property. a criteria can have only one child (which is saved in the DB, but it can have multiple parents) which I want to get from the db using @Formula.

I tried adding @Formula on the parent field definition but it seems not do anything.
When I added a getter for the parent

```
@Formula("(select from betsy.criterion where child_id=id)")
@Override
public List<Criteria> getParents() {
    return _parent;
}
```

I got:

```
org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a setter for property parent in class
enter code here`com.bge.domain.data.criteria.RangeCriteria
```

RangeCriteria extends AbstractCriteria.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Range_criterion")
@ForeignKey(name = "Range_criteria_id")
public class RangeCriteria extends AbstractCriteria {

  private double _fromRange;
  private double _toRange;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: if you use jpa @Formula, that sql must be the SQL not jpql and the error is that parent doesn't have set method.

Comment: It is a valid SQL. I checked it on my db. regarding the set method. I know it doesn't have a setter. that's on purpose, because it's a calculated property I don't want it to have a setter.

Comment: Can you post a little bit more code?

Comment: I added some of the definition code. Do you need more info?